# How to Use Plugins with PhoneGap Build 3.x?

Tags: plugins, cordova, build

I am writing a PhoneGap Build 3.x program, and cannot figure out how to properly configure my config.xml and index.html files to access any of the plugins.  Here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "org.kirsches.PGB"
        version   = "1.0.0">
    <name>PhoneGap Build Test</name>

    <description>PhoneGap Build Test</description>

    <author href="http://www.kirsches.org" email="mitch@kirsches.org">
        Mitch Kirsch
    </author>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
    <preference name="orientation"      value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device"    value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen"       value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />

    <gap:platform name="android" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
</widget>
```

and here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>PhoneGap Build Test</title>
      <script src="cordova.js"></script>
      <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
      <script >
         document.addEventListener('deviceready',
                                   onDeviceReady,
                                   false);

         function onDeviceReady() {
            alert("using PhoneGap 3.1.0");
            alert("model = " + device.model);
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>PhoneGap Build Test</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

The "using PhoneGap 3.1.0" alert fires, then the application hangs on my Android device.  Am I incorrect in assuming that I don't need to set up an AndroidManifest.xml file, since I am using PhoneGap Build (it is my understanding that PhoneGap Build generates the AndroidManifest.xml file from my config.xml file)?  Or, am I missing something in my config.xml file (it is my understanding that the feature tag is no longer used by PhoneGap 3.x)?

Thank you to anyone who can show me my error in the above two files.

Comment: Your assumption is correct that you don't need to set up the Manifest. Also, "Upgrading from 2.9.0 to 3.1.0" in the PG Build Docs should help.

Answer (score 0):

The only odd thing is the fact you include phonegap.js AND cordova.js. Pick one, it doesn't matter, as PhoneGap Build simply injects the correct file for you (as long as you have one of those tags). So in case you have: don't include the actual files.

Hope this makes a difference..
Eddy

Comment: If I only include either phonegap.js or cordova.js, then I get the following alert:

    [ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found

Comment: I wonder if I am not including the correct version of cordova.js or phonegap.js (I do not have either file in my code base, but rather, am relying on PhoneGap Build to generate them).

Answer (score 0):

Two things had to be changed in my code:

1. As Eddy correctly pointed out, I just needed phonegap.js or cordova.js (but, this was not causing my hanging problem).
2. I had to delete (uninstall) my app on my Android device and then re-install it via my bar code reader app (I use QR Droid).  I have enabled debugging and hydration on my app (since I am in the early stages of development), and I am guessing that a prior hydration operation must have corrupted something in my app.  The hanging problem occurred on two different Android devices, with the interesting scenario of the app simultaneously working correctly on Android device # 1 (since I had already done the delete and re-install on it) and not working on Android device # 2 (since I had not yet done the delete on re-install on it).

Two lessons I learned from this are:

1. You can't count on the hydration process to work all of the time!
2. Unless you are in the habit of changing the name of your application each time that you upload it to PhoneGap Build, clicking on the "Install" or the "APK" buttons or the bar code on the PhoneGap Build web page will bring down the most recent version that has been stored in Amazon S3, which might not be the most recent version that you uploaded to PhoneGap Build!

Mitch